What is the origin of vyaghra mukha found on top of idols?
I read somewhere in Padma Purana about origin of Vyaghra mukha can someone recount it here.thanks

Vyaghra means tiger. Do you mean tiger or Yazhi? Please put up with an image if possible, or at least give more description.

@Marmayogi He must have meant Kirthimukha

There is only one story regarding Vyāghramukha (“tiger-faced”) that I can find in the Padma Purāṇa chapter 6.125 (entitled “The Importance of Māgha As Told by Bhṛgu”)
The story explains how sage Bhṛgu, being afflicted with famine, migrated to the Himalaya mountains. There a Vidyādhara descended who had the face of a tiger (vyāghramukha). Bhṛghu explains the cause of his condition and also narrates how king Purūravas was afflicted with a similar condition.

130b-138a. “O best vidyādhara, listen to the strange fruit of (one’s) deeds. Having obtained it, the wise are not deluded, but the ignorant are deluded. As poison, just of the measure of the wing of a bee is dangerous, similarly even a small act, not enjoined, is dangerous in its effect. Having fasted on Ekādaśī, you smeared your body with oil. Due to that you have become tiger-faced (vyāghramukha) in the body of the previous existence on Dvādaśī. Formerly Purūravas, having fasted on the auspicious Ekādaśī but having used oil on the Dvādaśī obtained, like you, an ugly body. Seeing his ugly body, he was pained by that affliction. He went to the lord of mountains on the lake of the deities, and staying there with great joy, he bathed, and being pure, (sat on) a darbha-seat. The king, fasting, and, having controlled all his senses, and reflecting in his mind on Viṣṇu, dark green like a fresh cloud, having large lotus-like eyes, holding a conch, a disc, a mace and a lotus, covered with a yellow garment, shining with Kaustubha, wearing a garland of wood-flowers, practised a very severe penance for three months.

Edit: In case you were looking for, as suggested above, Kīrtimukha, have a look at the following story from Padma-Purāṇa chapter 6.10 (entitled “Jālandhara’s Messenger Rāhu Meets Śiva”):

31-35. Due to its heat, the crescent moon remained in the forest of his matted hair. She (i.e. the crescent moon) then became wet, and bathed his body (with) ambrosia; the row of the skulls on Śiva’s head was brought back to life. (And) it recited all the sacred texts in due order, which it had formerly studied. The heads, hearing recital (of the sacred text) done by one another, discussed it (i.e. started its discussion). “I am the first, I am before (you). I am the greatest, I am the creator. I am the protector.” In this way they eagerly bewailed one another: “I did not give gifts; I did not enjoy (pleasures); I did not offer oblations into fire. Due to my mind seized with grief, I did not give wealth to a brāhmaṇa.”
36-38. Then a great attendant of the lord, with a mass of twisted hair, appeared (there). He had three faces, three eyes, three tails and seven hands. He was the great (attendant) by name Kīrtimukha, having matted hair. Seeing him that row of the skulls remained as it were dead through fear. Then that attendant Kīrtimukha said in front of the lord Śiva, after saluting him: “O lord, I am very much hungry.” Then Śaṅkara told him: “O, eat those who are killed in the battle.”
39-43. That attendant thought for a moment; and not seeing the battle anywhere, went to eat Brahmā, but was warded off by Śiva. Then Kīrtimukha who was hungry and who was fully warded off, ate up all his own body. Seeing that rash act and the devotion of Kīrtimukha, the lord, being pleased, said to him: “Always stay in my palace. He who, living in my house, has no thought about you, will quickly fall down.” He who was addressed thus, vanished. At that time gods showered flowers on the head of Śiva.

When Nārada later recounts the story to Jalandhara, he says:

[Nārada said:]
28b-30. When the man thus ordered by Śiva ate up the flesh of his hands and feet, and when he remained with the head only, Śiva, seeing him with the head left, was very much pleased, and with amazement said to that man of fierce acts:
[The lord said:]
31. Having the name of ‘Kīrtimukha’ always remain at my door. Those who do not honour you, do not do what is dear to me.
[Nārada said:]
32-34. Since then Kīrtimukha remains at the door of the lord. The worship of those who do not honour him would be in vain. That Rāhu who was left by him fell on the Barbara region. Therefore, on the earth he is known as Barbarodbhūta Then Rāhu, thinking that he was reborn here, told all this done by Śiva to Jalandhara after approaching him.

